# How to use arrow key with .write function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to use left arrow key in name.write(u\2190) but the below error appears every time.

```
outfile.write(u'\u2190\u2190')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 
0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: @YSelf You saved my night, it worked like a charm <3

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
outfile.write(u'\u2190\u2190'.unicode('utf-8'))
```